How to replace "1" with a variable "productId"
The code below is working:
// WORK
keepThisCartItem = [{"p1": thesePlans}]

How can I replace the "1" with productId? I try below, but it did not work.
keepThisCartItem = [{ ["p"] + `${ productId }`: thesePlans }]

If possible, please help. Thanks a lot in advance!
I need to replace the "1" with the variable "productId"

try this one: keepThisCartItem = [{ \p${ productId }`: thesePlans }]`

Does this answer your question? How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?

There are many other potential duplicates as well.  The syntax for using a dynamic property name in an object literal is to enclose the expression which produces the name in square brackets.  For example, this would be an object literal with a dynamic property name: { ["p" + productId]: thesePlans }  You can also use template literals, or any other expression which results in a string.

@Or Keren , I apologize if it seems I copied your comment for my answer, I had been working on it and not seen your comment.

@Mippy All good, even upvoted you :)

Thanks a lot for you all helping me. I have just try both (A) keepThisCartItem = [{ p${ productId }: thesePlans }]   and  (B) { ["p" + productId]: thesePlans } Both (A) and (B) are working.

You can use a template string to add a custom productId to the "p".   A template string allows you to easily embed variables into a string.  This code should gives you something like [{p1: "something"}]
var productId = 1
var keepThisCartItem = [{ [`p${productId}`]: thesePlans }];


